# One view, post to multiple actions in one controller, Asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a User Account Management page that is backed by an open source membership library. My project is an Asp.Net MVC 4 application. The membership library provides an api that is very granular and allows the updating of User details with separate calls such as ChangeUsername(), ChangeEmail(), ChangePassword(), AddPasswordResetSecret(), RemovePasswordResetSecret().

The view I am building presents all these details to the user on one page, and the user has the ability to edit each of the separate sections and click the update button for each section once they are done. Basically when you want to change username, you click edit in the username section, change it and click the update button in that area. That should only affect the username. Changes to other areas will be the same, you can't edit all user details at once.

My question lies on the best approach to accomplish this. My controller will have separate actions for each of the different User details getting changed. Do I add separate models for each of the actions, and do I use multiple forms on the page, each form calling a different action, or can partial views cover this case for me, with each partial view calling a different action in the controller. The other thing I am thinking about is how I will handle the validation, with separate models for each action, each model will have its own valid state, but when validation breaks on the controller side how do I reload the page just displaying the one section as invalid and displaying the error message?

**So my questions are:**

1. Separate forms on one page?
2. Separate views or partial views on one page?
3. Separate models for each action?
4. How to handle model validation and page rendering on broken
   validation?

Comment: Please review MVC structure once. I'm sure you'll get most of your answers. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/overview/asp-net-mvc-overview